# Append first few rows of larger table to div

Tags: jquery

I've got a table, say with 6 rows and 2 columns. I want to append only the first 3 rows in a div.

I tried:

```
var table = $('#vidTable tr:lt(2)');
$('#divarea').append(table);
```

This seems to take the first two rows and tack them at the end of the table. Not what I'm after. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/0evg5erk/8/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle example puts the first three rows in the div. I don't see the problem.

Comment: `tr` is invalid child of `div`. It must be in table

Comment: If you looked at the resulting source in your jsFiddle, you would see that it only looks like it is at the end of the table. By adding a `margin-top` to your `div` you can see that it is in the div, not the bottom of the table. http://jsfiddle.net/xzLgo3ah/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `clone()` might be the solution to your problem.

```js
var table = $('#vidTable tr:lt(2)').clone();
$('#divarea').append(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="vidTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      One
    </td>
    <td>
      Two
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      three
    </td>
    <td>
      Four
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Five
    </td>
    <td>
      Six
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Seven
    </td>
    <td>
      Eight
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Nine
    </td>
    <td>
      Ten
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Eleven
    </td>
    <td>
      Twelve
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="divarea"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so this is what you expecting for

Use Slice

```
var table = $('#vidTable tr').slice(0,3);
$('#divarea').append(table);
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/0evg5erk/12/

Comment: regardless of how you filter the rows, resultant collection is no different using `slice()` instead of `lt()`